# How to swipe from one child group of expandable listview to another child group within he same parent group

Tags: java, android

I have an expandable listview, i want when an item is clicked on one can swipe to the next item on the list without going back to click on the next item.

I have tried using expandable listview and viewpager but both of the would not want to be in the same layout file, it is not working for me.

Please how do i go about this.

Comment: You can make this work with fragment which has ViewPager in it. ViewPager can have fragment container and in onPageChangedListener you can just replace one fragment with another. If its the same fragment but different data just provide it with new data and fill your fragment. Can you work with this?

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: I am having difficulties in implementing this, please more help.

Comment: Can you tell me which value type are you using for your ListView adapter? Please copy what you have so far here so I can help you

Comment: Ok, i will do so